# Function for probability distribution approximation of a compound random variable

Tags: functions, recursion, self-study

In the book (Klugman et al, 2019) on can see the

> **Example 9.12.** The number of claims has a Poisson–ETNB distribution with
> Poisson parameter  = 2 and ETNB parameters  = 3 and  = 0.2. The
> claim size distribution has probabilities
> 0.3, 0.5, and 0.2 at 0, 10, and 20, respectively. Determine the total claims distribution recursively.

I have solved this example with the [actuar](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/actuar/actuar.pdf) package in R. My code is below:

```
library(actuar)

fx = c(0.3, 0.5, 0.2)
size = 0.2
prob = 0.25
x.scale = 10 
lambda = 2

Fs <- aggregateDist("recursive",
                     model.freq = "zero-truncated negative binomial",
                     model.sev = fx, size=0.2, prob=0.25, x.scale = x.scale)

fx <- diff(Fs)

Fs <- aggregateDist("recursive", model.freq = "poisson",
                    model.sev = fx, lambda = lambda)
```

On can see the recursive method was used in the `aggregateDist()` function. This is the [Panjer recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panjer_recursion).

For comparison one can use the next output:

```
diff(Fs(0:4))  
[1] 0.11968449 0.12076747 0.10089972 0.08696367
```

**Question.** I am looking for an analog of the aggregateDist() function  in the Mathematica.

Comment: Since you say you solved the problem, edit the question to include that solution for comparison purposes.

Comment: @BobHanlon, I have added the output for comparison purposes.